# Найти общие элементы в двумерном списке

Tags: python, list, словари, производительность

Оригинал задания: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a6225e5d8e145b540000127

В кратце:

Дан двумерный список вида [[1,2,2,3],[5,3,2,2],[7,3,2,2]]

Нужно найти сумму всех общих элементов содержащихся в списках. В списке из примера общими элементами будут 2, 2, 3. Сумма их будет 7.

Быстродействие тоже важно, в комментариях писали, что задание возможно решить за O(N)...

Как я только не извращался, последнее решение было таким:

```
def common(a, b, c):
    dct = {}
    a = [a, b, c]
    for i in a:
        for j in i:
            if j in dct:
                dct[j] += 1
            else:
                dct[j] = 1

    return sum([(i * dct[i] // len(a)) for i in dct if dct[i] >= len(a)])
```

Но это решение, очевидно не проходит, т.к. список вида: [[1,2,3][2,5,3,2,2][7,3,2,2]] будет иметь сумму 5, а не 7, как получается у меня.

Так как же изменить скрипт, что бы учитывалось, что в одном подсписке может находиться несколько одинаковых значений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комментарии в коде

```
for lst in [[]], [[1, 2, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2, 2], [7, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2, 25]], [[1, 2, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2, 2], [7, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 25]], [[2, 5, 3, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 3, 2, 2]]:
    d = {}
    for i in lst[0]:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1  # формируем словарь вида {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}, где ключи - числа из первого подсписка, а значения - количество таких чисел в первом подсписке
    for u in lst[1:]:  # перебираем подсписки со второго до конца
        for k, v in d.items():  # обновляем значения в словаре как миминмум из количества ключей-чисел в словаре и очередном подсписке
            d[k] = min(v, u.count(k))

    print(sum(k * v for k, v in d.items()), ':', lst)  # перемножаем числа на их количество и суммируем
```

```
0 : [[]]
8 : [[1, 2, 2, 3]]
7 : [[1, 2, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2, 2], [7, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2, 25]]
5 : [[1, 2, 2, 3], [5, 3, 2, 2], [7, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 25]]
5 : [[2, 5, 3, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: OK, теперь по сути повторяет мой ответ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`&` для словарей-счётчиков работает как выбор минимального счётчика для ключа.

```
from collections import Counter
a=[[1,2,2,3],[5,3,2,2],[7,3,2,2]]

print(sum([k*v for k, v in (Counter(a[0])&Counter(a[1])&Counter(a[2])).items()]))
```

В условии задано три списка. Для большего количества делаем то же самое в цикле

```
cnt = Counter(a[0])
for i in range(1, len(a)):
   cnt &= Counter(a[i])
print(sum([k*v for k, v in cnt.items()]))
```